# Printing meters squared in R

Tags: r, printing

I wish to print meters squared in R but I’m not having success.
This is an example of the code I am working on:

```
bmi <- c(24,28,31)
print(paste0("Your body mass index is ", bmi, "kg/m^2"))
# [1] "Your body mass index is 24kg/m^2"
# [2] "Your body mass index is 28kg/m^2"
# [3] "Your body mass index is 31kg/m^2"
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Use the character `²`?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it so others know that you no longer need answers to the question and it disappears from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the UTF-8 Character "SUPERSCRIPT TWO", ² ([see here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)).
If you properly encoded your R script (or directly enter into the terminal), it'll work just fine.

If you don't have this option (or you can't type this letter), use the `\u` escape sequence: `\u00B2`

```
bmi <- c(24,28,31)
cat(paste0("Your body mass index is ", bmi, "kg/m²"), sep = "\n")
cat(paste0("Your body mass index is ", bmi, "kg/m\u00B2"), sep = "\n")
# Your body mass index is 24kg/m²
# Your body mass index is 28kg/m²
# Your body mass index is 31kg/m²
```

Newer R versions allow you to specify the file encoding with `source`, so that would be

`source("myFancyScript.R", encoding = "UTF-8")`